# 42crunch Schema does not define the type of JSON values for boolean

Tags: swagger, openapi, oas

I have a 3.0.3 OpenApi definition that contains a boolean in an object. The object has additionalProperties: false set

e.g.

```
    TestEvent:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        id:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/uuid'
...
        onDuty:
          type: boolean
          example: false
...
```

On performing a 42crunch audit, it has started to fail with the following error:
`Schema does not define the type of JSON values`

This is defined here:
[Description of error](https://apisecurity.io/encyclopedia/content/oasv2/datavalidation/schema/schema-notype.htm)

This is new. This OpenApi schema has been ok with this definition until recently.

Is this a bug at 42Crunch or do I have to change my OAS3 spec? If so, what do I need to change?

Comment: I assume `uuid` has its type set? Does the problem go away if you remove `onDuty` entirely (just for testing purposes)?

Comment: Which line of code does the tool complain about? Also, you can submit a ticket at https://support.42crunch.com and attach the OpenAPI file to the ticket so 42Crunch can reproduce the issue.